# How to enable Antialiasing in Finder's preview column and QuickLook?

Tags: finder, text, quicklook

The title pretty much says it all, plain text files are a bit annoying to read on QuickLook (and to preview on finder's preview column) due to a lack of antialiasing.

On the General preference panel I've checked that my text smoothing is set to ~“Turn off for sizes 4 and smaller”.

I've also checked with TextEdit that the font size in QuickLook is quite on the bigger-than-4 side, and that I can see the text antialiased in TextEdit.

Doing some googling I only found people with the same need but 0 solutions.

For the record: this is a brand new mac with OS X Lion 10.7.2 as fully updated as I can, that arrived home last week and I haven't (yet) installed any plugin at all for QuickLook.

Comment: I didn't find anything promising inside the `/System/Library/QuickLook/Text.qlgenerator/` bundle or in http://secrets.blacktree.com/?search=quicklook... I'd also like to increase the font size in addition to enabling anti-aliasing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to just use a different QuickLook generator. My generator of choice is [qlcolorcode](http://code.google.com/p/qlcolorcode/). Antialiasing works perfectly well with it and it'll even highlight source code files—which is its main purpose.

There is one bug, however, that if you are dealing with any directories or files containing a ' (single quote), there will be no QuickLook available for it due to the way the generator sends the path to the highlighter program.

Another downside is that the filename will not show in the QuickLook window. Instead, it will just say "Source file". It also will not work on textClipping files.

Comment: Hm… interesting. I was hoping something like that and had this other question http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1142/what-are-some-great-quick-look-plugins on another tab to try them all. Or in the worst case, make my own.